# How to split an array to separate subsequent similar items in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have an array like this

```
var array = [
  {
    category: 'smart phone',
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy Note 4',
    color: 'golden',
    index: '1'
  },
  {
    category: 'smart phone',
    name: 'Qmobile Noir A10',
    color: 'white',
    index: '2'
  },
  {
    category: 'smart phone',
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy note 8',
    color: 'black',
    index: '3'
  },
  {
    category: 'laptop',
    name: 'Dell inspiron n5110',
    color: 'black',
    index: '4'
  },
  {
    category: 'laptop',
    name: 'Macbook Pro',
    color: 'golden',
    index: '5'
  },
  {
    category: 'smart phone',
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy S5',
    color: 'white',
    index: '6'
  },
  {
    category: 'smart phone',
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy S3',
    color: 'white',
    index: '7'
  },
];
```

and want to split it based on the concurrent similar items. To achieve this if I apply the filter.

```
array.filter(item => item.category === 'smart phone');
```

it does not provide only the concurrent items, but it filters out all the items under 'smart phone' category.

```
arr1 = [
  {
    category: 'smart phone',
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy Note 4',
    color: 'golden',
    index: '1'
  },
  {
    category: 'smart phone',
    name: 'Qmobile Noir A10',
    color: 'white',
    index: '2'
  },
  {
    category: 'smart phone',
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy note 8',
    color: 'black',
    index: '3'
  },
  {
    category: 'smart phone',
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy S5',
    color: 'white',
    index: '6'
  },
  {
    category: 'smart phone',
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy S3',
    color: 'white',
    index: '7'
  },
];
```

What I am trying to achieve is something like this.

```
// output required
// concurrent items of smartphone category
arr1 = [
  {
    category: 'smart phone',
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy Note 4',
    color: 'golden',
    index: '1'
  },
  {
    category: 'smart phone',
    name: 'Qmobile Noir A10',
    color: 'white',
    index: '2'
  },
  {
    category: 'smart phone',
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy note 8',
    color: 'black',
    index: '3'
  },
];

// concurrent items of laptop category
arr2 = [
  {
    category: 'laptop',
    name: 'Dell inspiron n5110',
    color: 'black',
    index: '4'
  },
  {
    category: 'laptop',
    name: 'Macbook Pro',
    color: 'golden',
    index: '5'
  },
];

// again concurrent items of smartphone category
arr3 = [
  {
    category: 'smart phone',
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy S5',
    color: 'white',
    index: '6'
  },
  {
    category: 'smart phone',
    name: 'Samsung Galaxy S3',
    color: 'white',
    index: '7'
  },
];
```

How can I achieve this result in JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: theres no magic. if you want to achieve that, you should make a for loop to slice the input as you want. you cant use filter.

Comment: also, concurrent is a term in programming. your usage may sound quite confusing to others.

Comment: I can slice, if I do know the index to start and stop. the content is dynamic and I can't slice it randomly, I need to slice upto a point where the items' category is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to group the objects. Create a variable to keep track what the previous `category` was. If it's the same as the current `category`, push the object to the last array of accumulator. Else, push a new array to the accumulator.

```js
const array=[{category:'smart phone',name:'Samsung Galaxy Note 4',color:'golden',index:'1'},{category:'smart phone',name:'Qmobile Noir A10',color:'white',index:'2'},{category:'smart phone',name:'Samsung Galaxy note 8',color:'black',index:'3'},{category:'laptop',name:'Dell inspiron n5110',color:'black',index:'4'},{category:'laptop',name:'Macbook Pro',color:'golden',index:'5'},{category:'smart phone',name:'Samsung Galaxy S5',color:'white',index:'6'},{category:'smart phone',name:'Samsung Galaxy S3',color:'white',index:'7'},];

let previous;

const output = array.reduce((acc, o) => {
  if (previous !== o.category) {
    previous = o.category
    acc.push([o])
  } else {
    acc[acc.length - 1].push(o)
  }
  
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the array and take a new array for changing categories.

The result is an array of arrays where each array has the same category in the original order.

```js
var array = [{ category: 'smart phone', name: 'Samsung Galaxy Note 4', color: 'golden', index: '1' }, { category: 'smart phone', name: 'Qmobile Noir A10', color: 'white', index: '2' }, { category: 'smart phone', name: 'Samsung Galaxy note 8', color: 'black', index: '3' }, { category: 'laptop', name: 'Dell inspiron n5110', color: 'black', index: '4' }, { category: 'laptop', name: 'Macbook Pro', color: 'golden', index: '5' }, { category: 'smart phone', name: 'Samsung Galaxy S5', color: 'white', index: '6' }, { category: 'smart phone', name: 'Samsung Galaxy S3', color: 'white', index: '7' }],
    result = array.reduce((r, o, i, { [i - 1]: last = {} }) => {
        if (last.category !== o.category) r.push([]);
        r[r.length - 1].push(o);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so, using `reduce` with `slice` and destructuring:

```js
var array = [{category:'smart phone',name:'Samsung Galaxy Note 4',color:'golden',index:'1'},{category:'smart phone',name:'Qmobile Noir A10',color:'white',index:'2'},{category:'smart phone',name:'Samsung Galaxy note 8',color:'black',index:'3'},{category:'laptop',name:'Dell inspiron n5110',color:'black',index:'4'},{category:'laptop',name:'Macbook Pro',color:'golden',index:'5'},{category:'smart phone',name:'Samsung Galaxy S5',color:'white',index:'6'},{category:'smart phone',name:'Samsung Galaxy S3',color:'white',index:'7'}];
const [[arr1, arr2, arr3]] = array.reduce(([acc, cat], curr) => {
  curr.category == cat ? acc[acc.length - 1].push(curr) : acc.push([curr]);
  return [acc, curr.category];
}, [[]]).slice(0, -1);
console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
console.log(arr3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure: you need to assign the output of `.filter()`

```
let filteredArray = array.filter(item => item.category === 'smart phone');
```

Only writing `array.filter(your function)` won't change `array`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that was not what I was asking.